# Seesaw theorem for the pullback of a line bundle via projection map.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, pullback, line-bundles

I am trying to understand Mumford's statement of the Seesaw theorem given at the start of Chapter 3 in his book Abelian Varieties.

The statement is: Let $X$ be a complete variety, $Y$ a scheme (both over an algebraically closed field $k$) and $L$ a line bundle on $X \times Y$. Then there exists a unique closed subscheme $Z$ of $Y$ such that $L|_{X \times Z} = p_{Z}^{*}N$ for some line bundle $N$ on $Z$ and if $f \colon S \rightarrow Y$ such that $(1_{X},f)^{*}L = p_{S}^{*}M$ then $f$ factors through $Z$.

My questions are: What is $Z$ if $L = p_{X}^{*}N$ for $N$ a non-trivial line bundle on $X$ - is it $Spec(k)$? If so how does one prove it?

Intuitively, it seems to me that it should be $Spec(k)$, because the data of the line bundle all comes from $X$ so there should be no non-trivial subscheme of $Y$ over which $L$ is pulled back from.

Comment: What if $N$ is the trivial bundle?

Comment: @Mohan oh yes, you are quite right. Is it possible to give a general condition for when $Z$ will be trivial?

Comment: What does $Z$ trivial mean?

Comment: $Z = Spec(k)$. By a general condition I meant something along the lines of: if $z: Spec(k) \rightarrow Z$ is a geometric point in $Z$ then $L|_{X \times \{z\}}$ is trivial.

Comment: If you take $L=p_X^*N$, then $Z=Y$ if $N$ is trivial and $Z=\emptyset$ if it is non-trivial.

Comment: Okay, I shall edit the question to specify that $N$ is non-trivial. My question was how does one prove this. By $\emptyset$ do you mean $Spec(k)$? I was thinking that we were working in the category of schemes over $k$ - otherwise surely it doesn't make sense to say $X \times \emptyset$.

Comment: Empty set always makes sense. It has no points.

Comment: But how does one form the fibre product $X \times_{k} \emptyset$? Surely this requires a structure morphism $\emptyset \rightarrow Spec(k)$?

Comment: Of course, it is the usual open immersion $\emptyset \to Spec(k)$. $\emptyset$ is the initial object in the category.

Comment: Okay thank you. How does one define a morphism into $\emptyset$ which must exist for the fibre product to exist?

Comment: Sorry, I now understand that the fibre product $X \times_{k}\emptyset = \emptyset$.